# What would be the best way to UV unwrap this kind of mesh?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I'm trying to unwrap my mesh but it's just not the result I'm trying to get. There's stretching but if I use seams it will make those stripes even more misplaced. So does anyone have an idea of how to unwrap this kind of mesh to place stripes on?[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried unwrapping by "projecting from view"?

Comment: Yeah, but then how am I supposed to unwrap sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UV maps are like present wrapping in reverse. Use Mark Seam to Mark places on the mesh to “cut,” then UV -> Unwrap to create a UV map.

Think of how you would create this mesh if you were making it out of cloth, and then Mark Seam where the seams would be. Then, select all, and Unwrap.

Comment: Well, that more or less helped, I tried various edges and somehow it got unwrapped pretty clean for stripes to be on their places. But I think using "projecting from view" is a good fit too at some point.